# XGBRegressor loss functio custom

Tags: xgboost

I want to custom loss function to quantile loss(pinball loss) in XGBRegressor

I use this code

```
def xgb_quantile_eval(preds, dmatrix, quantile=0.2):
    labels = dmatrix.get_label()
    return ('q{}_loss'.format(quantile),
            np.nanmean((preds >= labels) * (1 - quantile) * (preds - labels) +
                       (preds < labels) * quantile * (labels - preds)))


def xgb_quantile_obj(preds, dmatrix, quantile=0.2):
    try:
        assert 0 <= quantile <= 1
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError("Quantile value must be float between 0 and 1.")

    labels = dmatrix.get_label()
    errors = preds - labels

    left_mask = errors < 0
    right_mask = errors > 0

    grad = -quantile * left_mask + (1 - quantile) * right_mask
    hess = np.ones_like(preds)

    return grad, hess
```

And I build model like this

```
def XGB(q, X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid, X_test):    
    # (a) Modeling  
    model = XGBRegressor(objective=xgb_quantile_obj, alpha=q,
                     n_estimators=10000, bagging_fraction=0.7, learning_rate=0.027, subsample=0.7)                 
                     
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, eval_metric = xgb_quantile_eval, 
          eval_set=[(X_valid, Y_valid)], early_stopping_rounds=300, verbose=500)

    # (b) Predictions
    pred = pd.Series(model.predict(X_test).round(2))
    return model, pred
```

But I got an error

```
models_2, results_2 = XGB(0.5, X_train_1, Y_train_1, X_valid_1, Y_valid_1, X_test)
results_2
```

- AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_label'

I am not sure if I am doing well. Please help me

Comment: check the ```shape``` of ```dmatrix```, ```get_label()``` returns 1-dimensional array. This might be the case that ```dmatrix``` is not 1-dimensional. As a workaround you can use ```dmatrix.Flatten()``` before the ```get_label()``` part but yes it depends on your dataset and requirement. It is advisable if you provide sample dataset which is worked upon and be specific about the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I catch the error, I have to change the sequence between preds and dmatrix in xgb_quantile_obj and change dmatrix to labels